# How to make Butterbeer?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter series, [Butterbeer](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Butterbeer) is the drink of choice for younger wizards. Harry was first presented with the beverage in Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban. Although House-elves can become intoxicated by consuming Butterbeer, the amount of alcohol present in Butterbeer has a negligible effect on Witches and Wizards. In her interview with Bon Appétit magazine, J.K. Rowling said that she imagines it "*to taste a little bit like less-sickly butterscotch*." Butterbeer can be served cold or hot, but either way it has a warming effect on the consumer.

**Is there any specific recipe for making Butterbeer?**

I know this is non-alcoholic, so how we can make it?

Comment: Isn't this is more appropriate for [Cooking.SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The recipe used at Wizarding World of Harry Potter at Universal Orlando is:

> **Butterbeer**
>
> Start to finish: 1 hour (10 minutes active)
>
> Servings: 4
>
> 1 cup light or dark brown sugar
>
> 2 tablespoons water
>
> 6 tablespoon butter
>
> 1/2 teaspoon salt
>
> 1/2 teaspoon cider vinegar
>
> 3/4 cup heavy cream, divided
>
> 1/2 teaspoon rum extract
>
> Four 12-ounce bottles cream soda
>
> In a small saucepan over medium, combine the brown sugar and water.
>   Bring to a gentle boil and cook, stirring often, until the mixture
>   reads 240 F on a candy thermometer.
>
> Stir in the butter, salt, vinegar and 1/4 heavy cream. Set aside to
>   cool to room temperature.
>
> Once the mixture has cooled, stir in the rum extract.
>
> In a medium bowl, combine 2 tablespoons of the brown sugar mixture and
>   the remaining 1/2 cup of heavy cream. Use an electric mixer to beat
>   until just thickened, but not completely whipped, about 2 to 3
>   minutes.
>
> To serve, divide the brown sugar mixture between 4 tall glasses (about
>   1/4 cup for each glass). Add 1/4 cup of cream soda to each glass, then
>   stir to combine. Fill each glass nearly to the top with additional
>   cream soda, then spoon the whipped topping over each.

Source: http://www.foxnews.com/leisure/2010/07/02/harry-potters-butterbeer-recipe-uncovered/#ixzz2HT5UxD00

Comment: No magic involved?

Comment: @MrLister : it is specifically forbidden (maybe by the nature of magic itself?) to summon or otherwise magically create food in the Harry Potter universe. So all wizard foods can be made by muggles as well, if they know the recipe. Yes, you could use magic to stir it, or to light the fire in the oven, etc. but that would not make the food any different.

Comment: So, to make this alcoholic, you could subtract the rum extract and the two tablespoons of water and add an ounce of actual rum?

Comment: @vsz, If magic wasn't used, then how were the Chocolate Frogs able to jump?

Comment: @Zoredache, If the chocolate itself was made normally then there isn't a problem. The prohibition is against creating food magically, not casting magic on food.

Comment: Not meaning to nitpick, but that isn't the official recipe; it's a guesstimate by fox news

Comment: That recipe is not complete. The allergy information for Universal Studios’ Butterbeer is available: http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-g6CCD-Fp38c/VLPqbTN-A2I/AAAAAAAADhk/Dkv9KLCsneg/s1600/004.JPG It includes “tartrazine.” Tartrazine is a synthetic lemon yellow azo dye primarily used as a food coloring.

Comment: @SillyButTrue That could be in the cream soda.

Comment: So what's the active ingredient that makes it intoxicating to elves?